# Trying to add some external code into project gives error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my project I want to add Speak Here code which is a sample code given on developer.apple.com site. It contain some .cpp & openGLES code and files. t gives me syntax error. I tried to solve this problem by renaming the .cpp file to .mm still it have the same problem. My project is window based application in XCode by using objective C.

```
If any one from have solution on this then please reply me as soon as possible.
```

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to leave the C++ file with .cpp extension and to create another Objective-C++ file, with .mm extension. Usually this way is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Might help if you posted 1) the error message, and 2) the code that the error message is complaining about.

Comment: error are 1) syntax error before 'Meter Table'#include <stdlib.h>
2)syntax error before {
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
class MeterTable
{

Comment: Should be a comment on the question